# Error while mysql table trying to import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing a site using php ( codeigniter ) and MYSQL. I use WAMP locally and then push changes to a shared hosting account. I'm getting an error in my production website with a particular table , so I decided to go into my remote phpmyadmin and export the table . I then added a prefix to my table locally to change it to "prefix_mytable" (i.e. rename it). I then tried to import the exported remote table locally. However I'm getting the following error:

```
1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Show us your schema, and if possible the data creating the conflict (fields with primary key 1)

Comment: do u want the local data? or do u want a duplicate of the remote in the local ?

Comment: I want duplicate of the remote in the local

Comment: when you export with phpmyadmin, choose custom and make sure to mark the field that says 'drop table if exists', or you can simply just drop the local database and recreate an empty one and use the backup that you already have